# Proving there is an $a$ that is not a quadratic residue mod $p$ for any prime $2 < p \leq 1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove there is an integer $a$ such that for all primes $p$ between $2$ and $1000$, the number $a$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Thanks.

Comment: is the range inclusive of $2?$

Comment: not homework , the range not inclusive of 2. (I prefer a clue..)

Comment: The smallest such $a$ for the first $30$ primes is greater than $10^8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that there is a quadratic non-residue for each prime, and use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

For each prime $p_i$, there is a quadratic non-residue $\pmod{p}$, so choose 1 of the quadratic non-residue(s) and call it $a_i$. Since $p_i$ are relatively prime, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists $a$ such that $a \equiv a_i \pmod{p_i}$ for all odd primes $p_i$ less than $1000$, so $a$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{p_i}$.

Comment: do we need to make sure that number will be $<1000?$

Comment: Well the OP didn't place any restriction on $a$. (Apart from being integer)

Comment: There is (p-1)/2 quadratic non-residues -> there is a for his there is no solution to  $x^2=a(modp)$ ..I don't succeed to use Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: ok, I will be happy to get full solution..

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something big time, I think Ivan's is a *full solution*: it proves the **existence** of such an $\,a\,$ . Now, to *actually* find it (i.e., its numeric value) may require looooong hours of very boring calculations, or a more or less simple computer program. Of course, +1 to the answer.

Comment: no, my bad... thanks!